# Concentration bound on additive functions with constraints

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Given a family of sets $F \subseteq P(\{1,\ldots,n\})$. I define the function $f_F:[0,1]^n \rightarrow R$ to be $f_F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)= \max_{S \in F} \sum_{j \in S} x_j$.

Given a series of independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with the support $[0,1]$, and a specific family $F$ such that $E[f_F(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] \geq c_1$, can I deduce that:
$$\mathrm{Pr}\big[\mid f_F(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-E[f_F(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] \mid > E[f_F(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]/2\big]  \leq c_2 \cdot e^{-\frac{c_1}{c_3}}$$
for some constants  $c_2,c_3>0$ that does not depend on the distributions nor $c_1,n$, and $F$?

Comment: Just to clarify: you *don't* assume that $X_j$ are identically distributed, just independent, right?

Comment: Right, the $X_j$ have different underlying distributions.